# Regex for decimal number validation in C#

Tags: c#, regex, c#-4.0

I need  regular expression which allows  positive as well as negative range decimals values

like `.89`, `-1000`, `0.00`, `0`, `300`, .....

My regex is   `^\d*\.?\d*`

Problem is that when you entered special characters like `$`, `!`, `*` then it accepts those characters.

Comment: So what's wrong with using `float.TryParse`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are keen on using `regex`, the following will do:

```
^-?[0-9]*\.?[0-9]+$
```

[See live demo](https://regex101.com/r/sL6zP7/2)

Answer (score 1):

Instead of regex, I would parse it with [`decimal.Parse`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.decimal.parse.aspx) with [`AllowDecimalPoint` and `AllowLeadingSign` styles](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.globalization.numberstyles.aspx) and a culture that has `.` as a [`NumberDecimalSeparator`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.globalization.numberformatinfo.numberdecimalseparator.aspx) like [`InvariantCulture`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.globalization.cultureinfo.invariantculture.aspx).

```
var d = decimal.Parse("-.89", 
                      NumberStyles.AllowDecimalPoint | NumberStyles.AllowLeadingSign, 
                      CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
```

This captures all needs you mentioned.

Answer (score 1):

You missed a backslash! A single dot has a different meaning in Regex expressions.

```
public static bool IsValidDecimal()
{
    string input = "132456789"
    Match m = Regex.Match(input, @"^-?\d*\.?\d+");
    return m.Success && m.Value != "";
}
```

Comment: It will fail for negative numbers, also for numbers with a decimal but no fractional part (like `1.`)

Comment: Even this one also works fine. Thanks @Jules. I had missed m.value!="".

Comment: I am sure this regex accepts `1.`, which is not a well-formed number!