# How to I condition a text box for a string if it holds a integer

Tags: c#, windows, vb.net

I'm currently having some issues with error checking on a textbox. It holds a variable (called Price) as Double. Its purpose is to take a number in, and when a button is clicked it adds it to a running total displayed in a different textbox.

Now I have an error when checking if the textbox is empty using:

```
!string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(txtAddItem.Text)
```

However, I'm unsure of how to error check if a string or character other than a number has been entered. Any ideas are appreciated.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Identify if a string is a number](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/894263/identify-if-a-string-is-a-number)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Method 1: RegEx**

You should try to use a regular expression. Regular expressions (Regex in short) are used to match strings against patterns. For example, if you only want to allow integers:

```
Regex r = new Regex(@"^[0-9]+$")
```

The [`Regex`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.text.regularexpressions.regex?view=netframework-4.7.2) class has an [`.IsMatch(string s)`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.text.regularexpressions.regex.ismatch?view=netframework-4.7.2#System_Text_RegularExpressions_Regex_IsMatch_System_String_) method, where `s` is the string you want to test against the pattern.

**Method 2: try-catch and Parse()**

Another way to do it, which might be a bit more beginner-friendly, is a try-catch block. (*I am assuming your TextBox's name is TextBox1 and you store the sum value in a runningSum variable.*)

```
try {
    double x = double.Parse(TextBox1.Text);
    runningSum += x;
catch (ArgumentException ax) {
    //handle if it is not a number in the TextBox
}
```

**Method 3: TryParse()**

A more advanced version which combines `try-catch` and `Parse()` is using the [`double.TryParse()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.double.tryparse?view=netframework-4.7.2#System_Double_TryParse_System_String_System_Double__) method which returns a true/false value based on whether conversion was successful or not.

```
double x;
if (double.TryParse(TextBox1.Text, out x)) {
    runningSum += x;
} else {
    //handle if it is not a number in the TextBox.
}
```

Comment: It is quite a thing to write an appropriate regular expression for the *floating point number* `double` (let me provide some correct values as examples: `.1`, `-.2`, `1.23`, `1e-2`, `-1E+1`)

Comment: Well, most often you don't really have to write these things yourself. You can just google them. I think the thing to take away from that method is its existence. :) See, it takes like 1 minute to find a pattern on SO: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33939770/regex-for-decimal-number-validation-in-c-sharp

Comment: *Counter examples* for an accepted answer pattern (`^-?[0-9]*\.?[0-9]+$`): `1E+1` and `-1e-1` (both *valid* but *not matched*)

Comment: I wonder if anyone will ever type "1E+1" into a TextBox in 2019. But you are right, it's true!

Answer (score 1):

If the value needs to be a valid `double` you could use 'double.TryParse'. Something like:

```
if (double.TryParse(txtAddItem.Text, out double price) == false)
{
  // Show error or clear textbox
}
else
{
  // Value is valid, add to total
}
```

Comment: Please,`!` instead of `== false` i.e. `if (!double.TryParse...)`

Answer (score 1):

You can use [`Double.TryParse()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.double.tryparse?view=netframework-4.7.2)

```
double number;
if (Double.TryParse(txtAddItem.Text, out number)) {
    Console.WriteLine("'{0}' is a valid double: {1}", value, number);
} else {
    Console.WriteLine("Unable to parse '{0}' as a valid double", value);
}
```